# Splitting a text file out to HTML docs

Tags: html, text

I have a single text file that contains 500+ HTML pages in it, can I seperate these out to the HTML files quickly?

I figured the  and  to indentify the start & end of each doc would work, but I'm not really sure how to write a script for this?

Comment: What programming language? What is the code each page starts with. Is it `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML codes are seperated by `<!DOCTYPE html>` tags, you could use this script written in python:

```
# text to html
# Parses through a text file and seperates HTML code into
# files like html1.html, html2.html, etc.
# The HTML files need to include <!DOCTYPE html> at the start!

# Usage: $ python text-to-html.py filename
# Example: $ python text-to-html.py testfile.txt

from sys import argv

filename = argv[1]

open_file = open(filename)
counter = 0

for line in open_file:
    if "<!DOCTYPE html>" in line:
        counter += 1
        new_filename = "html%d.html" % (counter)
        new_file = open(new_filename, "w")
    new_file.write(line)
```

Hope it helps!